# Optimizing memory usage in TimSort

Tags: c++, sorting, insertion-sort, timsort

I've written a simple implementation of TimSort, with which I sort structures that have fields for ID and Points (they're supposed to be test scores) like such:

```
struct funkc {
    int id;
    int punkty;
};


void insertSort(funkc arr[], int left, int right) {
    for (int i = left + 1; i <= right; i++) {
        funkc key = arr[i];
        int j = i - 1;
        while (j >= left && arr[j].punkty > key.punkty) {
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
            j--;
        }
        arr[j + 1] = key;
    }
}

void merge(funkc arr[], int left, int mid, int right) {
    int n1 = mid - left + 1;
    int n2 = right - mid;

    funkc* L = new funkc[n1];
    funkc* R = new funkc[n2];

    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        L[i] = arr[left + i];
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++) {
        R[j] = arr[mid + 1 + j];
    }

    int i = 0, j = 0, k = left;
    while (i < n1 && j < n2) {
        if (L[i].punkty <= R[j].punkty) {
            arr[k] = L[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            arr[k] = R[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    while (i < n1) {
        arr[k] = L[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }

    while (j < n2) {
        arr[k] = R[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }

    delete[] L;
    delete[] R;
}

void timSort(funkc arr[], int n) {
    const int RUN = 32;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i += RUN) {
        insertSort(arr, i, min((i + RUN - 1), (n - 1)));
    }

    for (int size = RUN; size < n; size = 2 * size) {
        for (int left = 0; left < n; left += 2 * size) {
            int mid = left + size - 1;
            int right = min((left + 2 * size - 1), (n - 1));
            if(mid < right)
                merge(arr, left, mid, right);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);

    int n = 0;
    cin >> n ;
    funkc* arr = new funkc[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        funkc f;
        f.id = i;
        f.punkty =  (rand() % 1000001);
        arr[i] = f;

    }

    timSort(arr, n);


    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << arr[i].punkty << " ";
    }

    delete[] arr;

    return 0;
}
```

However, the tests I'm trying to pass my program through, have a strict memory limit. It does fine enough in most cases, but for the test with over 22 million elements to sort, this implementation doesn't fit in the memory allowed. I'm looking for ways to somehow lower this algorithm's memory usage. The exact size of the test is 22500024 elements, and we're only allowed 42000 kB of memory, my program is just a bit above that, using 45244 kB

An idea I've tried was to move the L and R arrays out of the merge function and into the timSort function, so that they're not initialized multiple times in the

```
for (int size = RUN; size < n; size = 2 * size) {
        for (int left = 0; left < n; left += 2 * size) {
            int mid = left + size - 1;
            int right = min((left + 2 * size - 1), (n - 1));
            if(mid < right)
                merge(arr, left, mid, right);
        }
    }
```

loop, but it only broke what was already working, so I'm not sure if it was a good direction to go in.

I also tried adjusting the RUN size in TimSort, but it seems that it doesn't actually affect the memory used at all.

Comment: please post a [mcve]

Comment: what more should I add? the main function of the program? it didn't seem all that relevant since all I'm trying to do is optimize these functions, which I just simply call in main

Comment: if someone wants to compile and run this code they will have to add a `main`, they will have to declare an array and initialize it with some `funkc` elements. If you have this code, why not include it?

Comment: I am asking for it, because the main chunk of memory your program allocates is for the array to be sorted, but exactly that you arent showing.

Comment: alright, I added the main function. In my actual program, it accepts input from the user, but I figure generating random numbers in the point range allowed (up to 1000000) works just as well for testing

Comment: how much memory do you have available? 22 millions x 2 x sizeof(int) is already quite a lot

Comment: The exact size of the test is 22500024 elements, and we're only allowed 42000 kB of memory, my program is just a bit above that, using 45244 kB

Comment: thats useful information that you can include in the question too

Comment: Don't *guess* at the amount of memory used, calculate. On the other hand, there's plenty of in-place sorting algorithms. Using those makes it trivially easy to meet memory requirements.